# How can I use jQuery to target multiple levels of child elements in an unordered list?

Tags: jquery, css

In my multiple level unordered list, I've used jQuery to add sub-menu buttons next to parent elements. When clicking on these I've tried to add an additional class: `open` to all of the children elements – the `ul`, `ul li`, and `ul li a` contained within the parent.

At the moment, this commans is only travelling one level, working as far as the `ul li`, but it has no effect to the `ul li a` hyperlink tag contained within.

For example, if you look at my js fiddle – when opening the sub-menus, the sub-menu links should turn from blue to yellow. Likewise when the sub-sub-menu is opened, the links should turn pink – but in both levels of the menu, neither of these are given the `open` class when the buttons are clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/23/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>').insertBefore('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li');

    $('.submenu-button').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children().toggleClass('open');

     });

});
```

It's worth mentioning that I've also tried the following code below. I read that the .find selector targets multiple levels of child elements, but when put into practice this stops it working completely in my Wordpress theme (interestingly not in the fiddle) and neither the list items or the hyperlinks they contain are given the additional class.

```
$(this).next().toggleClass('open').find('ul ul li, ul ul li a').toggleClass('open');
```

Comment: use `>` to get direct child, eg:`ul > li > a`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this – however it only seems to work on the sub-sub-menu, in which the links turn pink, but not the sub-menu, where they stay blue. Do you know why that might be? https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/24/

Comment: Please add html for a [MCVE](/help/mcve) to your question. Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained.

Comment: Hi Sumurai8, I'm not sure I understand, how has my question breached these terms? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Pranav C Balan suggested, use direct child.

Note that using this method, you must list ALL elements on element tree.

```
ul > li > div.unimportant > span.random > a
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you Django, I've figured this out from your answer and about 20 minutes staring at the inspect element markup. What I did was remove the `ul` from what Pranav wrote initially, because the `.next` command had already selected the unordered list. So my final code is: `$(this).next().toggleClass('open').find('li, li > a').toggleClass('open');` 
Unfortunately the toggle buttons for the sub-menus are also toggling the `open`class on the sub-sub-menus, but I guess thats another issue for another day.